# Use "Contains" to match part of string in lambda expression

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

I have this MVC page where I have three different "input" elements, all the same class, using the jQuery autocomplete.  On any one of them I am doing this in the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetAllItemsEdit(string data, string source)
{
    List<TextValuePair> items = InventoryControlRepository.GetAllItemsTVP();
    var result1 = items.Where(item => item.Text.Contains(data.ToUpper())).ToList();
    return Json(result1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The items contain this:

```
TextValuePair tvp = new TextValuePair();
tvp.Text = item.ItemNumber + " - " + item.ItemDescription + " - SN: " + item.SerialNumber;
tvp.Value = item.ItemNumber;
list.Add(tvp);
```

So the text in the `Text` portion of the TVP has to be matched according to the source input field.  Any idea how to do this?  I would need to split up the `item.Text` field somehow and check for one of the essentially three columns of data to match the input from the page.

Thanks to Pete's answer I was able to get it done.  I had to add a field to the model, essentially a search field which contains the values I wanted for the Text field.

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetAllItemsEdit(string data, string source)
    {
        IEnumerable<ItemModel> models = InventoryControlRepository.GetAllItems();
        switch (source)
        {
            case "txtFindSerial":
                models = models.Where(x => x.SerialNumber.IndexOf(data, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1);
                break;
            case "txtFindItem":
                models = models.Where(x => x.ItemNumber.IndexOf(data, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1);
                break;
            case "txtFindDescription":
                models = models.Where(x => x.ItemDescription.IndexOf(data, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1);
                break;
        }

        var result1 = models.Select(item => new TextValuePair() { Text = item.SearchField, Value = item.ItemNumber }).ToList();
        return Json(result1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would search your initial items (before you made the into a list of `TextValuePair`) then you could do something like

```
IEnumerable<Item> items = originalItemsList;
switch (source)
{
    case "1": // or whatever this should be
        items = items.Where(x => x.ItemNumber.IndexOf(data, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1);
        break;

    case "2": // or whatever this should be
        items = items.Where(x => x.ItemDescription.IndexOf(data, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1);
        break;

    case "3": // or whatever this should be
        items = items.Where(x => x.SerialNumber.IndexOf(data, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1);
        break;
}


var result1 = items.Select(item => new TextValuePair() { text = item.Text, Value = item.ItemNumber }).ToList();

return Json(result1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

If you can't use the initial objects then I would probably do it like this

```
var result1 = items.Where(item => TextMatches(item.Text, data, source)).ToList();
```

and then have a method:

```
private static bool TextMatches(string text, string data, string source)
{
    // you may want to chose a better delimiter if your text description contains a " - "
    string[] textParts = text.Split(new string[] { " - " }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    switch (source)
    {
        case "1": // or whatever this should be
            return textParts[0].IndexOf(data, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1;

        case "2": // or whatever this should be
            return textParts[1].IndexOf(data, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1;

        case "3": // or whatever this should be
            return textParts[2].IndexOf(data, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1;
    }

    return false;
}
```